# Naming DataTable in a DataSet using SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have built a backend system that allows a user to add multiple content section, widgets etc.

I want to keep the queries to the SQL server to a minimum for performance reasons, this is my current flow:

1. I check my main table which widgets have been added.
2. I run through each row and build the 'batch' sql query that gets content from mulitple tables.
3. Call the completed list of queries.
4. I populate in a DataSet.

**Now for the problem:**

The tables will never be in the same order, and I can't find a way to name the returned tables.

**Is it best to just dedicate a column in each returned DataTable to specify what it actually is, and loop through the DataSet?**

**Or is there actually a way of naming the returned tables?**

Comment: I'd like to hear the answer to this.  My intuition would be to just add a column to the `SELECT` list in your queries that identifies  the result set.

Comment: Thx JNK, that is what I am currently doing in the mean time, but would be great if there's a way to name the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody replied with an answer for **specifying DataTables in a DataSet**, so I ended up adding a Column to each DataTable making it unique and "searchable" solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it automatically, as far as I know. You can give table mappings a try -> http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/08/03/why-dataset-creates-tablen-as-the-default-table-name.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the post, but not really what I am looking for, looking for a solution that is fully dynamic. But thanks anyway.